# математические операции внутри вектора

Tags: r, rstudio

у меня есть вектор с числами (положительными и отрицательными). Мне нужно к первому  элементу вектора прибавить второй элемент вектора, далее к сумме первых значений прибавить третий элемент вектора, далее к сумме первых трех элементов вектора прибавить четвертый элемент вектора и так далее до конца вектора. Как мне это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все гораздо проще

```
cumsum(c(1, 2, 3, -5, 6, 7))
```